# Floating point exception (core dumped) when using cin

Tags: c++, cin

I get an error saying Floating point exception (core dumped),if i initialise `t=1` instead of `cin>>t` , it is working fine.

My source Code is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t,z,i,l,w;

    cin>>t;
    char a[101];

    for(z=0;z<t;z++)
    {
        cin.getline(a,101);
        l=strlen(a);
        w=0;
        for(i=0;i<l;i++)
        {
            w=w+(int)a[i];
        }
        w=w/l;

        if(w%2==1)
        {
            for(i=l-1;i>=0;i--)
            {
                cout<<a[i];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(i=0;i<l;i++)
            {
                cout<<a[i];
            }
        } 
        cout<<"\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: So if a core was dumped, you will have examined the core file in your debugger, right? It will show you where the program crashed and what it was doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cin>>t;` doesn't read the linebreak. So when you call `cin.getline(a, 101);` it will directly return with an empty string.

This causes `l` to be set to `0` and, as division by zero isn't allowed, will crash your program at `w = w /l;`

You could fix part of your problem by replacing `cin>>t;` with `cin >> t; cin.clear(); cin.ignore();`. This will make `cin.getline(a, 101)` work as expected.

The next part of the fix would be to avoid reading empty data per se (e.g. by just pressing enter in the next line). Depending on how the program shall behave you could either retry reading until a valid string is set, or just skip execution of the empty string. I used the skip example in my adjusted version below.

I would also use more brackets to make clear what happens when (or at least use a readable indention).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t, z, i, l, w;
    char a[101];

    cin >> t; cin.clear(); cin.ignore(); //Remove leftovers from cin.

    for (z = 0; z < t; z++)
    {
        cin.getline(a, 101);

        l = strlen(a);
        if (l == 0) //Skip empty words
        {
            continue;
        }

        w = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) 
        {
            w = w + (int)a[i];
        }

        w = w / l;

        if (w % 2 == 1)
        {
            for (i = l - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                cout << a[i];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (i = 0; i < l; i++)
            {
                cout << a[i];
            }
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add this line after `cin >> t`:

```
cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

To ignore the `\n` character that is still in the input stream.

You will also need to `#include <limits>` to compile.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `cin.getline` in the first line of for loop reads a string of zero length and you divide by its length (=0) in the line `w=w/l`.

A floating point exception is an error that occurs when you try to do something impossible with a floating point number, such as divide by zero. And here it is happening.

Try to do a `cin.ignore` just before the for loop in order to take the newline out of `cin`'s buffer.